# How does one find all elements of the commutator subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry

I am taking my first Abstract Algebra course. We are using Fraleigh's textbook "Modern Algebra." I have this problem that asks:

> Find the center $Z(D_4)$ and the commutator subgroup of $C$ of the group of symmetries of the square $D_4$.

I am trying to figure out how to find the commutator subgroup without computing every single possible word "$aba^{-1}b^{-1}$". That is just so many computations. I do understand how to find the center though looking at the table 8.12. I can travel along the columns and the rows and if $(i,j)\neq (j,i)$ I know that this element is not a member of the center. All this feels so inefficient though. How can I use theory to expedite this process?

Here is a picture of $D_4$ from my textbook:
[image: $D_4$]

Comment: It is not really that ineficient in that case. It's less work than writing this long question que you wrote, at least!

Comment: A complete calculation of the center of $D_{2n}$ for generic $n$ can be found here: https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/center-of-dihedral-groups/

Comment: Inefficiency isn't necessarily a bad thing when learning new abstractions. If you start making the computations by brute force you'll start to see patterns, in this problem and in others. Then the theory will make more sense. In the dihedral group the rotations and flips will contribute in different recognizable ways. I'd also recommend learning cycle notation for permutations (don't know when Fraleigh introduces it - you might want to read ahead).

Comment: I see how I can calculate $Z(D_4)$, actually looking at the table seems pretty sensible, especially for small finite groups. I am still very confused about the Commutator Subgroup though. Could it be that the commutator subgroup related to $G$ \ $Z(D_4)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

All finite groups can be described by a set of generators. These generators are elements that permit every group element to be written as a word using these generators, and conversely every word consisting of generators determines an element of the group. In the case of the dihedral group $D_n$ two generators are sufficient to express any element of the group. In this case one generator is $r$, a rotation of order $n$ and an involution $s$ (e.g. a flip around the x-axis) having th property $s^2 = 1$. The interaction between $r$ and $s$ is described by the relation $srs = r^{-1}$ (which can also be written as $s^jrs^j = r^{(-1)^j}$). This permits us to write every element of the group as $r^is^j$ ($i=0,\ldots,4$ and $j = 0,1$). This permits us to write the calculations for the center and the commutator subgroup for an element "in general".

- For the center: an element $g = r^is^j$ commutes with $r$ if : $$ r^{-1} (r^is^j) r  = r^{i-1+(-1)^{j}}s^j = r^is^j$$ in other words if $j=0$. $g$ commutes with $s$ if $$ s(r^is^j)s = (sr^is)s^{j-1}s = r^{-i}s^j = r^is^j$$. This last is only possible if $n$  is even. The only elements of the center (i.e. that commute with $r$ and with $s$) are the identity and $r^m$ if $n$ is even and $n = 2m$.
- For the derived subgroup: the commutator of two general powers of $r$ or two powers of $s$ clearly gives the identity so the only commutators that are interesting take the form $$ r^{-i}sr^is = r^{-2i}$$. So the derived subgroup consists of the even powers of $r$. If $n$ is odd then this is the cyclic group of order $n$ otherwise it is the cyclic group of order $n/2$ .